# (Android Studio ) fatal error: error in backend: Code generation for MIPS-I is not implemented

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I change my computer since I did I cant get my app code compiled when I build my app I got an error when it tries to compile the ndk
in my gradle console I get this error

```
[armeabi] Install: libthomson.so => libs/armeabi/libthomson.so  
[x86] Install: libthomson.so => libs/x86/libthomson.so  
[mips] Compile: thomson <= sha1dgst.c  
fatal error: error in backend: Code generation for MIPS-I is not implemented
make: *** [obj/local/mips/objs/thomson/sha/sha1dgst.o] Error 1
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':Myapp:ndkBuild'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Users\TRAKA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is what I've tried
 - Installed appropriate JDK and set it up in Advanced Computer Settings same for NDK
 - Reinstalled the Android Studio Reinstalled the Android Studio with
   seperately installing Android SDK and updating it

Comment: Do you really want to build for MIPS? If not, specify an abiFilter and limit the ABIs you build for.

Comment: how can I do the abi filter or where can I find more information about that?